# gmail Password reset using php zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, gmail, google-apps, change-password

I am working on to **reset gmail password using php**, i have follow this [link1](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/OeUu6ef01PM;context-place=topicsearchin/apps/authorid$3AAPn2wQczsRcUJrApk1KBS21r-IfoSHLGpdmEFOZyHIdhATPuold3dQB9s3Jb4buZSdM4gIb-Z3cE%7Csort:date%7Cspell:false) and [link2](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.gdata.gapps.html). while run this code throw `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with message 'Expected response code 200, got 400`
Invalid request URI' in /usr/share/php/Zend/Gdata/App.php:717

**My code:**

```
 <?php

//Change this for your domain
$domain = 'http://www.gmail.com/';
$email = 'mymail@gmail.com';
$passwd = 'myoldpasswd';
$user = 'mymail@gmail.com';
$newuserpassword = 'mynewpasswd';

//Connect as admin to Google Appss
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Http_Client');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Gapps');
try {
  $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($email, $passwd, Zend_Gdata_Gapps::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME);
} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_CaptchaRequiredException $cre) {
    echo 'URL of CAPTCHA image: ' . $cre->getCaptchaUrl() . "\n";
    echo 'Token ID: ' . $cre->getCaptchaToken() . "\n";
} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_AuthException $ae) {
   echo 'Problem authenticating: ' . $ae->exception() . "\n";
}
$gdata = new Zend_Gdata_Gapps($client, $domain);

//Now change the user's password
$updateUser = $gdata->retrieveUser($user);
$updateUser->login->password = $newuserpassword;
$updateUser = $updateUser->save();
$user->login->changePasswordAtNextLogin = true;

?>
```

**Error:**

```
  PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /usr/share/php/Zend/Gdata/ClientLogin.php on line 150
  PHP Stack trace:
  PHP   1. {main}() /home/raj2/Documents/gmail/update.php:0
  PHP   2. Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient() /home/raj2/Documents/gmail/update.php:17
  PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: php_errormsg in /usr/share/php/Zend/Gdata/Gapps/ServiceException.php on line 173
  PHP Stack trace:
  PHP   1. {main}() /home/raj2/Documents/gmail/update.php:0
  PHP   2. Zend_Gdata_Gapps->retrieveUser() /home/raj2/Documents/gmail/update.php:27
  PHP   3. Zend_Gdata_Gapps->getUserEntry() /usr/share/php/Zend/Gdata/Gapps.php:938
  PHP   4. Zend_Gdata->getEntry() /usr/share/php/Zend/Gdata/Gapps.php:535
  PHP   5. Zend_Gdata_App->getEntry() /usr/share/php/Zend/Gdata.php:187
  PHP   6. Zend_Gdata_App->importUrl() /usr/share/php/Zend/Gdata/App.php:228
  PHP   7. Zend_Gdata_Gapps->get() /usr/share/php/Zend/Gdata/App.php:771
  PHP   8. Zend_Gdata_Gapps::throwServiceExceptionIfDetected() /usr/share/php/Zend/Gdata/Gapps.php:224
  PHP   9. Zend_Gdata_Gapps_ServiceException->importFromString() /usr/share/php/Zend/Gdata/Gapps.php:172
  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with message 'Expected response code 200, got 400
  Invalid request URI' in /usr/share/php/Zend/Gdata/App.php:717
  Stack trace:
  #0 /usr/share/php/Zend/Gdata.php(221): Zend_Gdata_App->performHttpRequest('GET', 'https://apps-ap...', Array, NULL, NULL, NULL)
  #1 /usr/share/php/Zend/Gdata/App.php(883): Zend_Gdata->performHttpRequest('GET', 'https://apps-ap...', Array)
  #2 /usr/share/php/Zend/Gdata/Gapps.php(222): Zend_Gdata_App->get('https://apps-ap...', NULL)
  #3 /usr/share/php/Zend/Gdata/App.php(771): Zend_Gdata_Gapps->get('https://apps-ap...', NULL)
  #4 /usr/share/php/Zend/Gdata/App.php(228): Zend_Gdata_App->importUrl('https://apps-ap...', 'Zend_Gdata_Gapp...', NULL)
  #5 /usr/share/php/Zend/Gdata.php(187): Zend_Gdata_App->getEntry('https://apps-ap...', 'Zend_Gdata_Gapp...')
  #6 /usr/share/php/Zend/Gdata/Gapps.php(535): Zend_Gdata->getEntry('https://apps-ap...', 'Zend_Gdata_Gapp...')
  #7 /usr/share/php/Zend/Gdata/Gapps.php(938): Zend_Gdata_Gapps->getUserEntry(Object(Zend_ in /usr/share/php/Zend/Gdata/App.php on line 717
```